# How to break long import statements into multiple lines in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a pretty long import statement in my JavaScript (ES6) file:

```
import { A, B, C, D } from '../path/to/my/module/in/very/far/directory/'
```

Is it OK to add new lines like this?

```
import { A, B, C, D } from
'../path/to/my/module/in/very/far/directory'
```

If not, is there any other way to write clean (keeping my code
within 80 columns) import statements in ES6 syntax using Babel?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions. `babel` is for questions for a *Python library* with said name. Also this doesn't have anything to do with Babel.js either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are the results from my test using `ESLint`.

**ESLINT PASSED**

```
import fs
from 'fs';
```

**ESLINT PASSED**

```
import
fs
from 
'fs';
```

**ESLINT PASSED**

```
import {
    moduleName
} from './my/module/file';
```

And the above code executes fine. I think you are good to go!

**NOTE**: This [`.eslintrc`](http://pastebin.com/AqsdUmUa) was used.

Comment: Are there any configurations where eslint will not pass?

Comment: But how do we break file path if it is very large, is it possible?

Comment: What if  you have `import {foo} from './longer_than_140_chars_path'`? Is there a legal syntax that allows splitting the path string in two?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the ES6 spec does allow whitespace - which includes newlines - between every token (unless otherwise restricted). Automatic semicolon insertion will not mess with you inside of import declarations either, so you're free to do

```
import
{
A
,
B
,
C
,
D
}
from
'../path/to/my/module/in/very/far/directory/'
;
```

or anything that is less extreme and better indented :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following syntax:

```
import {
  CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanDeactivate, CanLoad, Route,
  UrlSegment, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree
} from '@angular/router';
```